# Free Web Hosting

Tags: web-development

i want to launch(publish) my site on the internet? so some one can tell me about free hosting?

Comment: That's a really broad question. Try to be more specific.

Comment: I agree, more info needed.  Is it PHP, .NET, straight HTML, or something else?

Comment: What kind of content are you planning to have? Text, images, and video, or is it some kind of application?

Comment: Windows Azure also has 10 free sites per region currently.

Answer (score 1):

One Amazon EC2 instance is now free for 12 months: http://itmanagement.earthweb.com/netsys/article.phpr/3909631/Amazon-To-Offer-a-Year-of-Free-EC2-Apps-Use.htm

So that is not free for ever, but *very* good free hosting for a year (if you know - or want to learn - how to manage your own server).

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are basic, Weebly might work. A few others that come to mind, but have more limited features for free service are DevHub, Unbounce, and Orbs.

(Sorry I can't add links, I don't have the reputation for it yet.)

Answer (score 0):

buy a domain from godaddy.com u get a host for free (very simple one though)